# Certificate Subscriber Agreement

Tags: certificate-authority

So, I decided to get an EV SSL certificate and I'm struggling to fill in some field on the agreement.

Never done this before, anyone could help me figure this out for me?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is for the type of company you are... such as an LLC, C-Corporation, or Non Profit.

If you're unsure, look at your DUNs filing or your state incorporation papers.  The person who owns the company or manages the legal paperwork (accounting?) will have this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your organization name or EORI number in the place